# Convert the second element in a nested array from a string into an int

Tags: python

I was wondering if someone could help me convert a nested element that is originally a string into an int in python without the use of pandas.

```
x=[('cat', '2'),('dog','3')]
```

to

```
x=[('cat', 2),('dog',3)]
```

I have tried to do as per below; however, it only works for a regular list without words.

```
r = list(map(int, x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this solution

```py
x=[('cat', '2'),('dog','3')]
r=[(a, int(b)) for (a, b) in x]
```